# Dell XPS 15 9520 Screen Brightness not detected in Fedora

Tags: fedora, brightness

Fedora 38 doesn't detect the laptop screen brightness capability after a fresh install, before it was working fine, Debian and Ubuntu do, what could be the reason, Fedora installation media even comes with a newer kernel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.